# Validation difficult as form fields contain "undefined" instead of nothing

Tags: jquery, validation

Many answers here about jQuery form validation recommend checking either `val() === ''` or `length() > 0`, but neither works with me as my empty form fields always contain "undefined". Why is that and what's the solution?

Comment: You'll get more help if you post code which at least shows context. Your `html` and validation `js` would do

Comment: Sometimes a problem exists regardless of the code used and the code is then NOT needed. Here'the HTML code: <input class="name" type="text"> and JS code: $('form').submit(function() { alert($('.name').val()); }). This is what I said in code format. The code adds precisely nothing in this case.

Comment: My intention is/was to help. `val() === ''` and `length() > 0` work just fine when used (for example) within a text field on `blur` or `submit`. Anyone can use the `html` and `css` you "provided" and not reproduce the issue. However given your short explanation and no context, you'd be better served providing more. After all this is a collaborative platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `typeof` to validate if field is undefined before checking it if empty.

```js
var validateText;
var validateArray = [];
if(typeof validateText == "undefined"){
  console.log("empty text");
}

if(typeof validateArray[1] == "undefined"){
  console.log("error array");
}
```